Customize sidebar items with docusaurus-plugin-openapi
I have been trying the Docusaurus OpenAPI plugin for my API documentation. But it is very hard for me to customize it the way I want. For example, how do I change what appears in the sidebar items? Instead of the the label being the summary, I want it to be the method + endpoint. See image.

Is it possible to override the method that generates de sidebar?
Thanks

maybe you can specify sidebar items in file. https://docusaurus.io/docs/sidebar/autogenerated#category-item-metadata

try removing the summary property. it's not required by the schema

If you do not want the sidebar title to be the doc.md title/summary, you can defined a category for that doc to fall under, which allows you to name a sidebar item and it's position.
Create a Category
A category is constructed of a folder within your docs folder that contains a _category_.config.js file with the following contents:
Example _category_.config.js:
{
    "label": "Sidebar Name",
    "position": 4
}

You will then place your .md file in that folder with the _category_.config.js file.
Refer to the required file structure for this:
Docusaurus site
└── docs folder
    ├── .md example file (exisiting file)
    └── .md category FOLDER
        ├── _category_.json
        └── .md file (will now be under the category name of the _category_.json file)

